# Podman cannot pull image

Tags: podman

I had have docker, but it has conflicts with my Fedora 31 and I had to remove docker:

> dnf remove docker-ce
>
> rm -rf /var/lib/docker

because Podman is more suitable to work with. But hence after running

> dnf install podman

I have docker and postman installed on my system. So, when using command:

> podman pull fedora:latest

this log appears, which seems to be a some sort of conflict there

```
    Trying to pull docker.io/library/fedora:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 5c1b9e8d7bf7 done  
Copying config 536f3995ad done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
  Error processing tar file(exit status 1): there might not be enough IDs available in the namespace (requested 192:192 for /run/systemd/netif): lchown /run/systemd/netif: invalid argument
Trying to pull registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 00c5bb959822 done  
Copying config 8c2e0da7c4 done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
  Error processing tar file(exit status 1): there might not be enough IDs available in the namespace (requested 0:12 for /var/spool/mail): lchown /var/spool/mail: invalid argument
Trying to pull registry.access.redhat.com/fedora:latest...
  name unknown: Repo not found
Trying to pull registry.centos.org/fedora:latest...
  manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Trying to pull quay.io/fedora:latest...
  error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>\n"
Error: error pulling image "fedora:latest": unable to pull fedora:latest: 5 errors occurred:
    * Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256:5c1b9e8d7bf7b758fa84807a6bce45e4af333e1ddd566b5972550b6fcfbed9b8": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): there might not be enough IDs available in the namespace (requested 192:192 for /run/systemd/netif): lchown /run/systemd/netif: invalid argument
    * Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256:00c5bb959822a02c8bce18fe3ff0193c39ff19c4c25c59b3638677e87d1ddb36": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): there might not be enough IDs available in the namespace (requested 0:12 for /var/spool/mail): lchown /var/spool/mail: invalid argument
    * Error initializing source docker://registry.access.redhat.com/fedora:latest: Error reading manifest latest in registry.access.redhat.com/fedora: name unknown: Repo not found
    * Error initializing source docker://registry.centos.org/fedora:latest: Error reading manifest latest in registry.centos.org/fedora: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
    * Error initializing source docker://quay.io/fedora:latest: Error reading manifest latest in quay.io/fedora: error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>\n"
```

I tried to remove docker, but bash deletes it along with podman.

Answer (score 2):

you are using rootless (running containers as non root) but it seems your user has not enough additional IDs available.

You need to make sure there are enough ids allocated for your user, please take a look at `subuid(5)` and `subgid(5)` to see how to configure it

After you set additional IDs for your user, you'll need to run `podman system migrate` to recreate the user namespace

Answer (score 0):

The error says `requested 192:192 for /run/systemd/netif` ie this image has files owned by UID 192 and you are running podman as rootless. Due to that, the image would not fit into rootless Podman's default UID mapping, which limits the number of UIDs and GIDs available.

Do `cat /etc/subuid` and check UIDs allocated for your user and probably could set additional IDs.

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rootless-podman

Answer (score 0):

As @Giuseppe Scrivano wrote above, issue might be with files /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid
As a source: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rootless-podman:
"This file is formatted as :<start_uid>:, where start_uid is the first"

So, I just added a line with "my-username":100000:65536 and it worked

- replace "my_username" with yours